# THREE.CubeTextureLoader 1px edges bug

Tags: javascript, three.js, panoramas

I create panorama cube using THREE.CubeTextureLoader:

```
pano = [
    'scenes/4/2048/px.jpg', 'scenes/4/2048/nx.jpg',
    'scenes/4/2048/py.jpg', 'scenes/4/2048/ny.jpg',
    'scenes/4/2048/pz.jpg', 'scenes/4/2048/nz.jpg',
];
newCubeTexture = cubeTextureLoader.load(pano);
geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20000, 20000, 20000);
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    envMap: newCubeTexture,
    side: THREE.BackSide,
    color: 0xffffff,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0
});
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

But when textures loaded I see 1px bug on the edges.

[image]

Why it's heppend?

P.S. If I load textures for each sides using map all good!

```
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(arr[i]),
    side: THREE.BackSide,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0
});
```

Comment: An `envMap` is for reflections, not for the purpose you are using it for. Search for `skybox` in the three.js examples, and see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310880/comparing-methods-of-creating-skybox-material-in-three-js

Comment: Problem only in envMap? Can I use cubeTextureLoader for map attribute and solve problem?

Comment: See how the skybox is implemented using `THREE.ShaderLib[ "cube" ];` in http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap.html.

Answer (score 0):

@WestLangley has good points in his comments. In addition to those, I would like to point out that the method of artificially creating a giant box has some weaknesses, in that it is still distorted, and can be susceptible to z-fighting on the borders.

A better alternative in modern versions of three.js is to assign a the `CubeTexture` from `cubeTextureLoader.load` to `scene.background`.